# Simple URL route

Tags: php, html, mysql

On my index page, I list all the post in the database

```
<?php

//include functions
include 'functions.php';

//READ
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post');
            //query
$stmt->execute();
$contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

HTML

```
<!-- FLEXBOX Container -->
            <div class="Elementi">
                <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): ?>

                <!-- FLEXBOX Items -->
                <div class="Cards">
                    <a class="links" href="read.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">
                        <img src="IMG/Immagine 1.png" alt="immagine 1">
                        <div class="Categorie">
                            <p class="Testo_categorie"><?=$contact['category']?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="testo_contenuto">
                            <h2><?=$contact['title']?></h2>
                            <p><?=$contact['main']?></p>
                            <h6>[READ]</h6>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

When I click on the image of one post I'd like to be redirected to a page (read.php) where I can read that post

```
<a class="links" href="read.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id] ?>">
    <img src="IMG/Immagine 1.png" alt="immagine 1"></a>
```

When I click on the image I actually am redirected to read.php but the URL doesn't print the ID and in the page I can't see the information about the title, category, and text.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is $id where Do you set it shouldn't it be $contact['id']

Comment: Don't speak in terms of "noob problems". We all have problems.

Comment: it would be `href="read.php?id=<?= $contact['id'] ?>"` then obviously use `$_GET['id']` inside read.php to query by id